# error Status: 'Internal Server Error'. Error Code: 500 - jqGrid ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using jqgrid Modal form to Add and Edit rows of the table. I am using Entity framework and Database First approach to create models from existing database. When I Add or Edit the rows, rows are added or edited correctly and being saved appropriately in the database and when I retrieve the added or edited rows and view in jqGrid, they are displayed correctly. But, the only issue is when I Add or Edit, it throws ***error Status: 'Internal Server Error'. Error Code: 500*** in the modal form.

Anyone has any idea of why is this happening? Since, the add or edit is happening properly, is there a way that I can ignore this error message and make it not displayed at all?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

```
public ActionResult Create(string oper, string id, Employee employee)
{
try
{
 if (oper == "add")
 {
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
    db.Employees.Add(employee);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");   
   }
 }
 if (oper == "edit")
 {
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
 }
  if (oper == "del") 
  {
    Employee employees = db.Employees.Find(Int32.Parse(id));
    db.Employees.Remove(employees);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
}
```

Comment: You should debug the code which will be executed on the server side on Add/Edit operation. The code have a bug which produces an exception. You can debug the code step by step for example to find the reason of the problem.

Comment: Run the site with the debugger attached, and I'm sure you will see the exception being thrown. Otherwise, use browser debugger tools (Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, IE Developer Tools) to inspect the returned data from the request, which should be a YSOD

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for your suggestion. I have debugged the code and the weird thing is that it doesn't throw any exception, I have placed the code in try/catch and noticed that no exception is thrown. I am able to view all the exceptions I got before I was able to successfully add/edit the records and dealt with them appropriately. But, after the records were added/edited properly, no exception is caught but still this error is thrown. That's what I am confused. Any suggestions to somehow deal with this error which is not being caught on the server side?

Comment: @AndrewBurgess: I am getting this error when adding/editing the record, and not expecting any data in return and I was using the debugger to debug the server side code but no exception is caught. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @inspiringmyself: Probably you used wrong format of the data and the code of "Add"/"Edit" implementation of the server side was not executed at all. Do you debugged the code locally? Is the corresponding method was called? You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Network tab of Developer Tools of IE or Chrome to trace HTTP traffic. In any way the error 500 means that the request of jqGrid produced some error in the server code (probably in ASP.NET part of the code before your code was called). You should post some code fragments.

Comment: i was caught up in similar kind of problem, thanks to Oleg, i debugged my code, and the problem i got is that i was sending null values from my view to controller. So, first if you can open fiddler and confirm that data is going to the server and going in correct format and then are you writing the right parameters in ur controller method to accept that data?

Comment: and as i rightly said by Oleg, please put some code here

Comment: HTTP 500 errors means that a client request was made to your server and then your server said "Woah, something ain't right here". You should at the very least be getting a YSOD back (during AJAX requests, this doesn't show up in the page content, so you have to inspect the response returned in some sort of browser/HTTP tool like mentioned above)

Comment: @Oleg: Yes, I debugged the code locally and the method is called properly and I was able to step through each line in the method till the data is saved properly into the database. So, I am pretty sure the code is executed completely without any error since I was able to see all the values properly retrieved and the changes get successfully changed. I am sure no exception is thrown while debugging the code since not exception is caught in the catch block. I am sure all the values are saved in the right format too, this makes me go crazy..I will post my controller action implementation...

Comment: @PiyushSardana: Yes, I am sure I am sending the data in the right format and I am able to debug and see all the data are retrieved and saved properly. I will post my code now..

Comment: Your controller seems fine to me, you mind posting you view code?

Comment: @PiyushSardana: Thanks a lot for trying to help me out. I will post my  javascript in a bit, in the meantime, can you take a look at my another question posted here...any suggestion is really helpful. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750121/closeafteredit-not-working-after-editing-the-form-jqgrid

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all your suggestions. I finally figured out what I was doing wrong, please take a look at the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for all your suggestions. I figured out what I was doing wrong. Actually, the issue is not with incorrect data format or the code not being hit, the problem was after I saved changes to my database, that's why it was not caught in the exception block.

After saving the changes to the database as [db.SaveChanges()], I am redirecting to the Index Action. That's where the issue was. I was redirecting to the wrong Index action. The code inside this Index action tried to return some value that is null and hence ArgumentNullException was thrown and that displayed YSOD.

Note: I was able to spot the ArgumentNullException with Event Viewer. Type Event Viewer in Run and the Goto Windows Logs - Application. You will be able to see all the Warnings for your application. Open the warning, Goto General tab and you will be able to see what kind of exception is thrown. Hope this helps someone in need.