# error Status: 'Internal Server Error'. Error code: 500 in jqgrid while deleting a record

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, jqgrid-asp.net

I want to delete a record in jqgrid but I get the error:

> Error status: 'Internal Server Error'. Error code: 500

while performing delete. I want to delete a record from database. Please tell me where is the mistake. My code is:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="display:table">           
  <div style="display:table-row">
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-row">            
      <div id="divSurvey"></div>  
      <table id="tableSurvey"></table> 
      <button type="button" ID="btnedit"  value="Submit" runat="server">Submit</button>  
          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               jQuery("#tableSurvey").jqGrid
               ({
                url         :'FetchGridDetails.aspx',
                datatype    :'json',                 // data which will be filled
                mtype       :"GET",
                postData    :{Fill: function(){return 'Survey'}},
                contentType :"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                jsonReader  :
                            {
                                root:"rows",
                                page:"page",
                                total:"total",
                                records:"records",
                                repeatitems:false
                            },
                colNames    : //Define column Names
                            [
                                'SurveyID',
                                'EnquiryID',
                                'AccountID',
                                'AccountType', 
                                'SurveyType',
                                'BranchID',
                            ],
                colModel:
                [
                    {
                        name    :'SurveyID',
                        index   :'SurveyID',
                        align   :'center',
                        width   :150,
                        key     :true,
                        editoptions:{ readonly:true }
                    },
                    {
                        name    :'AccountID',
                        index   :'AccountID',
                        align   :"center",
                        width   :150,
                        editable:true
                    },
                    {
                        name    :'SurveyType',
                        index   :'SurveyType',
                        align   :"center",
                        width   :150,
                        editable:true
                    },
                ],
                rowNum          :8,
                rowList         :[10,20,30],
                pager           :'#divSurvey', // id of div tag...(Pager)
                sortname        :'SurveyID',
                sortorder       :"desc",
                viewrecords     :true,
                emptyrecords    :"No RECORDS FOUND",
                loadonce        :true,
                editurl         :'EditGridDetails.aspx', //code for delete
                width           :'500px',
                multiselect     :true,
                shrinkToFit     :true,
                forceFit        :true,
                sortable        :true,
                autowidth       :false,
                height          :"100%",
                width           :"100%",
                ignoreCase      :true,
                gridview        :true,
                pageable        :true,
                serverPaging    :true, 
                modal           :true,
                scrollable      :false,                    
                caption         :"Survey Details"          
               }).jqGrid
                    (
                        'navGrid',
                        '#divSurvey',
                        {
                            edit    :false,
                            add     :false,
                            del     :true,
                            search  :false,
                            view    :false
                        }
                    );
           });
          </script>
```

Comment: It may be because of your server page where you might have got an exception check code in your aspx page

Comment: it may not be the problem with your jqgrid code it may be problem with your code in .aspx page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743904/error-status-internal-server-error-error-code-500-jqgrid-asp-net-mvc